# Prove that there is no non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ such that $P(n)$ is a prime number for all positive integers n

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers

Prove that there is no non-constant polynomial $P(x)$ such that $P(n)$ is a prime number for all positive integers $n$.
Appeared in an undergrad entrance exam. I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: an entrance exam to what class??

Comment: Bachelor s in mathematics.

Comment: In indian statistical institute

Comment: Try focusing on the degree of the polynomial: how often can we decrease from $n$ to $n+1$ with respect to the degree?

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $P(x)$ satisfies this property. Let $p=P(1)$.

We know that $p\mid P(kp+1)$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$, so $P(kp+1)=p$ for all $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. If you aren't convinced, note that $(kp+1)^i\equiv1\pmod p$.

This is impossible since for any non-constant polynomial, the preimage of a given value must have finite cardinality (consider the polynomial minus the value, that would have infinite roots otherwise), but this implies that $$\{kp+1\mid k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}\subset P^{-1}(p)$$

Comment: I have the impression that you suppose that the coefficients are integers, to prove that P(kp + 1) is divisible by p. Is it the case ?

Comment: No,  the assumption is that the output is integral.